# Flutter firebase, how to retrive user data and have it on the map or a list

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I saw many examples on internet, but in each case, the data is returning on a listview.  I don't want to print in a listview. I want to use data in the app.
This is the way I am addind data on firebase.  (I am using a class Info).

```
 void infouser(context) async {
      final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
      final info = Info(yourname, animaName, yourmail);
      final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
      await db.collection("userData").doc(uid).collection("info").add(info.toJson());
    }
```

I also tried with set,

```
createInfo(context) async {
      final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
      DocumentReference documentReference =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Animal').doc(uid);
      Map<String, dynamic> todos = {
        'name': yourname,
        'animalname' :animalName,
        'email' : yourmail,
      };
      documentReference.set(todos).whenComplete(() {
        print( yourname, animalName, yourmail
        );
      });
}
```

In both case, I was only able to print data on a Listview. But that is not what I want. I want to have data on a list or a map to be able to use it elsewhere in the app.
Please, I if you have a link(or give me a example of code) where I can see example, it will be appreciate.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the example of retrieving data as map from firestore:

```
    class GetUserName extends StatelessWidget {
      final String documentId;

      GetUserName(this.documentId);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

        return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: users.doc(documentId).get(),
        builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
          return Text("Full Name: ${data['full_name']} ${data['last_name']}");
        }

        return Text("loading");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I advise to use https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/? documentation when working with Firebase from flutter